# Unable to Start the SDL Web Translation Manager service

Tags: web8.5, sdl-tridion

[image: Tridion Translation Manager Service start issue]

Please find the snapshot which i am getting an error while start the Service, Help me to resolve the issue.

Comment: Check is there any error message in event viewer?

Comment: Also, check the translation configuration details are correct and valid XML? check database connection string & MTSUser and TMS endpoint URL details?

Comment: Do you have any Translation Manager extensions installed?

Comment: I've seen this before when the license was invalid....check the event log....

Comment: @NicholasRobichaud, Yes, we do have installed the Translation Manager extension which is <add assemblyFileName="D:\Tridion\Translation Manager\Tridion.TranslationManager.TcmExtension.dll"/>.